# Long initial loading time to load?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

We looked out the best platform out in the market, we selected ionic for the start. With all the trust, we kept on shifting and updating our application from VERSION 1, VERSION 2 and now VERSION 3 on ionic with your progress.

We are now stuck at the loading time of the application which takes 2 minutes to load.

Here is the issue,

In version 3

- There are 23 page in ClassHours. We have separated all of them to `@NgModule`.
- Earlier all the component and pages were included in **app.module.ts**.  Now only myapp page, the browser module, and HTTP module are included.

Still, the size of the mainjs is 4mb which makes the build heavy. It takes 2 minutes load for any user to load the application.(Refer image).

Here is the link for our testing site 54.254.254.112. Please check the issue here and make it a mobile view.

( Credentials for our testing account 
mobile number - 0000000000
password - 000000 )

Here is the deployment process we are using -

```
ionic build browser
```

copy `/www` from `/platforms/browser` to **ec2 amazon instance**
and run **nginx** pointing **index.html** of `/www`

Service worker is also enabled, which helps us improve the second load time.

Guide us with -

1. How can we reduce the size of mainjs from 4mb?

or

2. Is there some issue with deployment process?

How can we reduce the first time load time?

We need your guidance to run toward a neat and fast user experience.

Shall wait for a positive response.

Time taken by main.js:
[image: Time taken by main.js]

Comment: have you tried building with `--prod --release` flags?

Comment: Thanks suraj, Yes that's how it is fixed. Thanks a ton man!

Comment: ok.. adding answer..

Answer (score 1):

For building for production, use `--prod --release` flags.

```
ionic build browser --prod --release
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3 with `ionic build`, `--prod` will result in it using minification, AoT compilation etc and get your main.js file down considerably (I see it's now 745KB)

I haven't found a definitive answer (and I think it will depend on what you're doing in your app) but you should be able to use the "non cordova" build in `/www` instead of `/platforms/browser/www`. This basically doesn't include all those cordova plugin js files, almost halving the number of requests to your server. (also no config.xml and splashscreen)

The contents of `/www` might not be minified depending on what you last built, so you need to do a `--prod` build, which can either be from `ionic build browser --prod` or you can run `npm run build --prod` (undocumented) to just build `/www` in prod mode.

The produced `index.html` still contains a reference to `cordova.js`. You can either manually delete that or just leave a 0 byte cordova.js on your server (1 extra request). Or do both, in case you forget to remove it.

Your `splash.gif` is 1.5MB, by far the biggest file. In my browser it also only starts loading after main.js has finished. Rather have a look at some nice CSS based "spinners" and then include it inline in your `index.html`. Or you can just use your logo in the middle of the page.
Eg:
https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/
http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

By not including cordova you wont have the splash screen plugin so no splash screen, but fortunately you can stick some code inside your `<ion-app></ion-app>` in `index.html` and that will be used instead while loading the website (and ignored if you ever compile and actual app).

I also noticed your nginx server isn't doing any gzip compression. This can reduce the transferred data for `main.css` and `main.js` a lot (maybe 1/3 of the size).

Another neat "trick" you can use to at least increase the perception of loading faster is to style your actual `index.html` directly (inline style so no additional requests) to include your background image.

TL;DR:

1. Use `--prod`
2. Use Gzip compression
3. Skip cordova
4. Edit index.html to add a lightweight splashscreen, remove cordova.js, style it inline a bit like your app